# Different behavior on Firefox in comparison to other browser

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using the following template for my web page:
http://webredox.net/demo/html/betadesign/checkout.html

The layout on Firefox is not working well, as the details of the item under "You order" e.g. decription (Men's Belt) and option (Color: Red, etc...) are not displayed on firefox.
The template is working well on other browser.
I wondering if this is not a floating problem?
Do you have any ideas, how to solve the problem?

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a float issue. Add class pull-left to both the image and .media-body to solve the issue.